# Морфологический состав слов "отчий" и "заячий"

Tags: словообразование, морфология, суффиксы, окончания

Заяч-ий: *ий* суффикс или окончание? (Заячий тулуп.) Отч-ий: *ий* суффикс или окончание? Будьте добры, расскажите поподробнее об этой путанице с *ий*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заяч/ий - зячь/его, ИЙ/Й -  притяжательный суффикс, входит в основу, ЕГО - окончание.

Отч/ий - отч/его, ИЙ, ЕГО - окончания.

Comment: А вот одна составительница сборника для подготовки к олимпиаде считает, что *отчий* имеет тоже нулевое окончание. Кстати, в словобразовательном словаре оба эти слова помечены знаком "Нулевая суффиксация". Составительница ошибается? И что значит нулевая суффиксация в словообразовательном словаре?

Comment: В "Морфологии современного русского языка" указаны 4 типа склонения прилагательных: 1) обычное; 2) притяжательные прилагательные с ОСНОВОЙ на j (лисий, волчий); 3) притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксами  ИН/ЫН, ОВ/ЕВ (мамин, отцов) 4) несклоняемые (рококо). Отец - отчий, основы сущ. и прилаг. совпадают, суффикс нулевой.

Comment: В слове отчий ИЙ- окончание, потому что Й (йот) пропадает при склонении: к отчему дому. Будь это суффикс - йот бы сохранялся при склонении.